# android 2.2 google map error

Tags: android

I used google.map api to develop a project which works well on android 2.1. But when I run the same project on android 2.2, it encountered some errors. The shown errors are

> --  AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION:main
>   --  AndroidRuntime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener
>
> --  AndroidRuntime at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:199)

I don't know where is the problem? Can anyone help me? 
I will apreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. start the emulator with Target Name Google APIs, **API level 8, Platform 2.2**
2. pull the file /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar from the emulator and push into your phone dir /system/framwork.
3. pull the file /etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml from the emulator and push into your phone dir /etc/permissions.
4. restart your phone and try again.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This error may appear in some random, poorly supported devices that don't correctly implement the functionality required by some Google products like maps.

Just encountered this error myself on a Phone Model : Elonex1012ET, whatever that is!