# NetworkConnectivityListener class not found on UPC300-2.2 Viewsonic G-Tablet

Tags: android

I am getting this error in my application, and this happens **only** on *UPC300-2.2 Viewsonic G-Tablet*. All answers I've found so far (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011285/android-2-2-google-map-error)) adviced on putting

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to the manifest file, but it doesn't help.

Here is the complete stacktrace:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener
> ```
>
> at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:199)
>   at
>   myapp.Activity.ActivityMapSearch.onCreate(ActivityMapSearch.java:99)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Answer (score 0):

If that is TRUE, you can grab the source code of the class from the [Android Source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java) and add it yourself

Comment: Are you sure it would work? android.net.NetworkConnectivityListener is called from android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate and not from my code directly

Comment: I am not so sure. Can you try?

Comment: unfortunately not, because I don't have UPC300-2.2 on hand. The error I described comes from error log of one of my applications which is published on Android market.